# Error: "Cannot find method setValues(string)"

Tags: javascript, string, google-sheets-api

I am trying to get the values that states No in one of my columns. 
Receiving correct output when using Logger to check output, but receives error message when I ran the actual code.

```
function rides() {
        // source spreadsheet
      var url = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1fRc20zW1j....");  
      // source sheets
      var ss = url.getSheetByName('Master'); 
      var rides = url.getSheetByName('rides'); 

      var Drivers = ss.getRange('C2:C40').getValues();
      var Names = ss.getRange('B2:B40').getValues();


      for (var i = 0, len = Drivers.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (Drivers[i][0] == "No") {
              rides.getRange('A2:A40').setValues(Names[i][0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this value rides.getRange('A2:A40') is undefined, you wont get any access to the methods. That why the error is showing

Comment: `rides.getRange('A2:A40')` doesn't seem to contain the method `setValues` when that error is thrown. (Maybe it's undefined?)

Comment: I'm not quite understanding why it would be undefined. Correct me if im wrong and keep in mind I'm fairly new to js. Isn't that defining the range where I want the output to go? And within my sheets has the same amount of rows and columns. Thank you for the help guys

Comment: I have changed the sheets column header differently from my Master sheet, but all of them have 14 rows and 40 columns. Hope this info helps

Comment: I checked if Im even getting a single value from setValue() method I am using the same codes. Im not understanding why it's not working when i am trying to get multiple values using setValues().

Comment: [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) requires an array of array of values. [`setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)) requires a single value. Neither method will "get multiple values" from the `Range` you call them on - they are setter methods, not getters. If you want to set the value of a single cell, or of every cell in a given Range, to be one specific value, then use `setValue(thatValue)`

Comment: which one can I use to get multiple values within a column?

Comment: I cannot believe it, you were actually helpful for something @tehhowch